# From asp.net page excel file has data twice

Tags: asp.net, excel

I have a .aspx page in a asp.net web site that does nothing but opens a dataset and passes it to an Excel Helper class which builds a XML file and sends it as a response to a browser. I run it on my development machine - works perfectly.

It downloads the file - I open it using Excel - it is perfect.

I publish the web site to my test server on the network. Run the page again, over the same database getting exactly, precisely the same data and it returns the file - BUT - the data in the file is duplicated and Excel reports the file is corrupted.

The first line of the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

and the last line is

```
</Workbook>
```

On the development site, that is how the file downloads and it runs fine.

Downloading the exact same data from the Test site, the code is exactly the same - but it is duplicated. What should be the last line ...

```
</Workbook>
```

in the file downloaded from the test server the last line is ...

```
</Workbook><?xml version="1.0"?>
```

and the whole of the data is repeated again. It is exactly repeated. It is not that the code is looping twice, because, if it did, I would get Worksheet1 and Worksheet2 - but I don't - I get Worksheet1 repeated.

Any ideas please? Driving me nuts. Wasted a whole day on this so far.

Code that writes file is:

```
public static void ToExcel(DataSet ds, string fileName, HttpResponse response)
{
    string excelXML = GetXML(ds, filename); //this builds the XML data
    response.Clear();
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    response.Write(excelXML);
    response.Flush():
    response.End();
}
```

Please ignore typos - just had to type that out as I can't copy from my (remote) dev machine.

Comment: Is this an XLS or an XLSX file? Can you please **provide the code** that's writing the file to the response?

Comment: Are you running it in IIS when testing locally?

Comment: Also, what does the network tab in your browser dev tools show?

Comment: To mason: Have added the code that writes the file:

To G_P: Testing locally just running it frpm within Visual Studio.

Comment: The network tab shows nothing.

Comment: Nothing helpful, or *nothing* nothing? :) It should at least show the request and response from the server. You could try to remote debug it on the server and see if that helps determine what might be happening.

Comment: How do you remote debug a compiled web site on the server?

Comment: Nothing at all shows on the network tab.